# How to resolve ambiguity when using namespaces within inline namespaces

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces

I use inline namespace for versioning, but sometimes name conflicts arise because it exports all symbols into its parent scope. Is there a way around this? Except flattening namespaces of course. Removing `inline` is also not an option because it breaks source-code compatibility.

An example:

```cpp
namespace ns {
inline namespace v1 {
namespace detail {
// implementation detail
}
class [[deprecated("use v2::some_class")]] some_class
{
    // ...
};
} // namespace v1

namespace v2 {
namespace detail {
// implementation detail
}
class some_class
{
    // ...
};
} // namespace v2
} // namespace ns
```

So far all well and good. However when another `detail` within parent namespace gets introduced, all goes to hell:

```cpp
namespace ns {
namespace detail {
class impl {};
} // namespace detail 
} // namespace ns

void f()
{
     ns::detail::impl i; // error: 'detail': ambiguous symbol
}
```

I want content `ns::v1::detail` to get merged into `ns::detail`, not to conflict with it.

P.S. Looks like it happens on MSVC only. Just checked with GCC and Clang, they produce no such error. Which compiler is correct in this case?

Comment: Is it absolute necessary or could you also do `namespace default_ns = ns::v1; namespace ns{ using namespace default_ns; ... }` ( https://godbolt.org/z/TddP5fz51 )?

Comment: It isn't *really* necessary, your way also works, although it is less convenient.